# GCP Linux Instance issue

Tags: linux

We have a test Linux server in GCP and configured with tomcat server and mysql server with 50GB disk storage. We wanted to take a SQL dump, due to space constraints the sql dump couldn't be created completely. While generating the dump it has used the remaining space available on the disk and failed. After that SSH terminal got closed automatically and I'm unable to connect back since then. Then I increased the disk size of the instance from 50 GB to 80 GB, but still, it is not working. While connecting through SSH, it shows SSH authentication failed and asked me to check the logs in serial console. I have also tried to stop and start the instance, but it doesn't help. Here is the log I'm getting in the serial console. Could you please assist me in this.

```
Oct 10 10:29:56 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Oct 10 10:29:56 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Oct 10 10:29:56 tomcat-server-1 snapd[14607]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Oct 10 10:30:50 tomcat-server-1 google-accounts: ERROR Exception calling the response handler. [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/'].#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 200, in WatchMetadata#012    handler(response)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_daemon.py", line 285, in HandleAccounts#012    self.utils.SetConfiguredUsers(desired_users.keys())#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_utils.py", line 318, in SetConfiguredUsers#012    mode='w', prefix=prefix, delete=True) as updated_users:#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 679, in NamedTemporaryFile#012    prefix, suffix, dir, output_type = _sanitize_params(prefix, suffix, dir)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 269, in _sanitize_params#012    dir = gettempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 435, in gettempdir#012    tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 370, in _get_default_tempdir#012    dirlist)#012FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']
Oct 10 10:31:26 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Oct 10 10:31:50 tomcat-server-1 google-accounts: ERROR Exception calling the response handler. [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/'].#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 200, in WatchMetadata#012    handler(response)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_daemon.py", line 285, in HandleAccounts#012    self.utils.SetConfiguredUsers(desired_users.keys())#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_utils.py", line 318, in SetConfiguredUsers#012    mode='w', prefix=prefix, delete=True) as updated_users:#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 679, in NamedTemporaryFile#012    prefix, suffix, dir, output_type = _sanitize_params(prefix, suffix, dir)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 269, in _sanitize_params#012    dir = gettempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 435, in gettempdir#012    tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 370, in _get_default_tempdir#012    dirlist)#012FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']
Oct 10 10:32:50 tomcat-server-1 google-accounts: ERROR Exception calling the response handler. [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/'].#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 200, in WatchMetadata#012    handler(response)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_daemon.py", line 285, in HandleAccounts#012    self.utils.SetConfiguredUsers(desired_users.keys())#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_utils.py", line 318, in SetConfiguredUsers#012    mode='w', prefix=prefix, delete=True) as updated_users:#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 679, in NamedTemporaryFile#012    prefix, suffix, dir, output_type = _sanitize_params(prefix, suffix, dir)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 269, in _sanitize_params#012    dir = gettempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 435, in gettempdir#012    tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 370, in _get_default_tempdir#012    dirlist)#012FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']
Oct 10 10:32:56 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: snapd.service: State 'stop-final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Oct 10 10:32:56 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Oct 10 10:32:56 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Oct 10 10:32:56 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 10 10:32:56 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Oct 10 10:32:56 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Oct 10 10:32:56 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: Starting Failure handling of the snapd snap...
Oct 10 10:32:56 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: Started Failure handling of the snapd snap.
Oct 10 10:32:56 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 10 10:32:56 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Oct 10 10:32:56 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Oct 10 10:32:56 tomcat-server-1 snapd[14703]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Oct 10 10:33:50 tomcat-server-1 google-accounts: ERROR Exception calling the response handler. [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/'].#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 200, in WatchMetadata#012    handler(response)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_daemon.py", line 285, in HandleAccounts#012    self.utils.SetConfiguredUsers(desired_users.keys())#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_utils.py", line 318, in SetConfiguredUsers#012    mode='w', prefix=prefix, delete=True) as updated_users:#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 679, in NamedTemporaryFile#012    prefix, suffix, dir, output_type = _sanitize_params(prefix, suffix, dir)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 269, in _sanitize_params#012    dir = gettempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 435, in gettempdir#012    tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 370, in _get_default_tempdir#012    dirlist)#012FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']
Oct 10 10:34:27 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Oct 10 10:34:50 tomcat-server-1 google-accounts: ERROR Exception calling the response handler. [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/'].#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 200, in WatchMetadata#012    handler(response)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_daemon.py", line 285, in HandleAccounts#012    self.utils.SetConfiguredUsers(desired_users.keys())#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_utils.py", line 318, in SetConfiguredUsers#012    mode='w', prefix=prefix, delete=True) as updated_users:#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 679, in NamedTemporaryFile#012    prefix, suffix, dir, output_type = _sanitize_params(prefix, suffix, dir)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 269, in _sanitize_params#012    dir = gettempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 435, in gettempdir#012    tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 370, in _get_default_tempdir#012    dirlist)#012FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']
Oct 10 10:35:50 tomcat-server-1 google-accounts: ERROR Exception calling the response handler. [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/'].#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 200, in WatchMetadata#012    handler(response)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_daemon.py", line 285, in HandleAccounts#012    self.utils.SetConfiguredUsers(desired_users.keys())#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_utils.py", line 318, in SetConfiguredUsers#012    mode='w', prefix=prefix, delete=True) as updated_users:#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 679, in NamedTemporaryFile#012    prefix, suffix, dir, output_type = _sanitize_params(prefix, suffix, dir)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 269, in _sanitize_params#012    dir = gettempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 435, in gettempdir#012    tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 370, in _get_default_tempdir#012    dirlist)#012FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']
Oct 10 10:35:57 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: snapd.service: State 'stop-final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Oct 10 10:35:57 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Oct 10 10:35:57 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Oct 10 10:35:57 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 10 10:35:57 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Oct 10 10:35:57 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Oct 10 10:35:57 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: Starting Failure handling of the snapd snap...
Oct 10 10:35:57 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: Started Failure handling of the snapd snap.
Oct 10 10:35:57 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 10 10:35:57 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Oct 10 10:35:57 tomcat-server-1 systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Oct 10 10:35:57 tomcat-server-1 snapd[14801]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
```

Comment: Log in on the console, or mount the disk image to another instance and create free space. When you expand the disk you make the image file bigger, you still have to rewrite the partition table to increase the space of the partitions.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have mounted the disk image on another instance and freed up the space. Now it's working fine.